# Yii2 redis cache over file cache

Tags: php, caching, redis, yii2

I am using a yii2 with file cache and redis cache also. In my main config file redis cache settings are defined.

```
'redis' => [
        'class' => 'yii\redis\Connection',
        'hostname' => 'MY_IP',
        'port' => MY_PORT,
        'database' => 0,
    ],
```

I also added a component under file cache setting.

```
'cache' => [
        'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
    ],
```

so for a caching i'm using a `$cache = Yii::$app->cache;` and for setting a cache `Yii::$app->cache->set($id, $value, $time);`  and get using `Yii::$app->cache->get($id);`  so is this is set the value from file cache or it is override the filecache and using the redis over it.

If this is using the filecache so how we override the filecache with redis .Can we use the redis cache with this `Yii::$app->cache->get($id);` or we can use the redis with the `use yii\redis\Cache;` and set using the

```
$redis->hmset('test_collection', 'key1', 'val1', 'key2', 'val2');
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can by simply setting the `$cache` property to this:

```
'cache' => [
    'class' => 'yii\redis\Cache',
    'redis' => 'redis' // id of the connection component as it is already defined
];
```

In my code I'm using it this way:

```
 $cache = Yii::$app->cache;

 $cache->add($access_token, ['id' => Yii::$app->user->id], $expire);

 $user = $cache->get($access_token);
```

I've also noticed that some components are already using it like the [urlManager](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-urlmanager.html) which started storing the generated rules in the redis DB. See [yii\redis\Cache](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-redis-cache.html) docs for full list of available properties and methods when using within **$cache**.

Comment: in your cache setting your class is defined is redis but you are using $cache = Yii::$app->cache; instead of $redis = Yii::$app->redis; so this is storing in redis or file cache.

Comment: yes in redis as I made the `cache` component to use `yii\redis\Cache` instead of `yii\caching\FileCache`. Now both components **cache** and **redis** should use the same redis DB, you can use both. the only difference is that within `Yii::$app->cache` you can do simple stuffs like add and get (see the docs I linked). for using more advanced redis related methods like `hmset()` you will need to call them within the `$redis` component.

Comment: Ok. when we use file cache it will create a file for runtime for storing cache, according to you after defining the property class of redis it will not create a file in runtime it will use from redis db.

Comment: yes. that is how it works. the **cache** component is the one used by Yii to cache things and always accessible within `Yii::$app->cache`. in configs you set the class to be used by that component, it can be a file, redis or whatever else. In runtime in this case I think it will steal adding a file but holding redis related stuffs.